# Adding a list to a dictionary with the simplest code in python 3.x

Tags: python, dictionary

The inventory parameter is a dictionary representing the player’s inventory and the addedItems parameter is a list. The addToInventory() function should return a dictionary that represents the updated inventory.The program should output the following:

```
Inventory:

45 gold coin
1 rope
1 ruby
1 dagger

Total number of items: 48
```

Here's my code:

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    print('Inventory:')
    totalItem = 0
    for i in range(len(addedItems)):
        if addedItems[i] in inventory:
        inventory[str(addedItems[i])] += 1
    if addedItems[i] not in inventory:
        inventory[str(addedItems[i])] = 1
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(str(v) + ' ' + k)
        totalItem += int(v)

    print('Total number of items:' + str(totalItem))

inv = {'gold coin':42,'rope':1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin','dagger','gold coin','gold coin','ruby']
inv = addToInventory(inv,dragonLoot)
```

I was wondering how to work on the for loop bit. It seems strange to me now (and way too long). Thx!

Comment: For one thing, you can change your second `if` to `else`.  You don't need to recheck if `addedItems[i]` is in `inventory`.

Comment: @Joey did you get it to work?

Comment: @zondo Changed that one too.

Comment: @timgeb Yes it worked! thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should use a `Counter` for this, which is a subclass of the builtin dictionary.

It has three advantages for your use case:

- It is very easy to add two `Counter` instances (i.e. two inventories together).
- It is very easy to update a `Counter`.
- The `Counter` will automatically return 0 when you look up any item that is not in the inventory.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> inventory = Counter({'gold': 45,
...                      'rope': 1,
...                      'ruby': 1,
...                      'dagger': 1}
... )
>>> 
>>> def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
...     inventory.update(addedItems)
... 
>>> addToInventory(inventory, ['gold', 'gold', 'gold', 'dagger'])
>>> inventory
Counter({'gold': 48, 'dagger': 2, 'rope': 1, 'ruby': 1})
>>> addToInventory(inventory, {'ruby':100})
>>> inventory
Counter({'ruby': 101, 'gold': 48, 'dagger': 2, 'rope': 1})
>>> inventory['gold']
48
>>> inventory['flux capacitor']
0
```

Comment: Wow! I've just been learning Python for around a week and I never got to know all these subclasses. Is there a way to learn all of them systematically? Reading the official documents?

Comment: @Joey if you really wanted to learn the standard library *systematically*, you'd have to read a reference like the "Python Essential Reference" by David Beazley, which is probably a bit dry to read cover to cover. You'll learn a lot of commonly used classes by hanging around SO and constantly striving to improve your own code. Grab a reference when you are looking for something specific or just skim it from time to time.

Comment: okay, working on it right now:) You've been a huge help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make it look like this:

```
for i in range(len(addedItems)):
    inventory[i] = inventory.get(i, 0) + 1
```